# Vuetify - How to automatically pick the first element in a AutoComplete component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want the first element of all the AutoComplete components in my page to be selected automatically.

This is the HTML in Vue

```
<template v-slot:[item.classes]="{ item }">
    <v-autocomplete
        v-model="item.classes"
        :items="getClassifications(item.id)"
        :item-text="displayClassDesc"
        item-title="description"
        item-value="code">
    </v-autocomplete>
</template>
```

This is the getClassifications() method

```
    getClassifications(p_id) {
      let classes = [];
      for (let c of this.classifications) {
        if (c.Product_ID == p_id) {
          classes = c.classes;
        }
      }
      return classes;
    },
```

[This is the image of the data that is in the AutoComplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXHsZ.png)

Comment: In version 3.3, you just have to set the property auto-select-first on true: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props-auto-select-first

Answer (score -1):

This is of top of my head. I can check it when I get to my computer. In meantime check it out.

```
getClassifications(p_id) {
  let classes = [];
  for (let c of this.classifications) {
    if (c.Product_ID == p_id) {
      classes = c.classes;
      // Set the initial value to the first item
      if (classes.length > 0) {
        this.$set(item, 'classes', classes[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  return classes;
}
```

Comment: As said in the comments, there is a build-in functionality for this.

Comment: I know, I just posted it in case he is not using needed version. I will delete answer if it's not useful.